# Pass values from angular app to php file and conversely

Tags: php, mysql, angular, promise

I use Angular 4 for a project, and I now want to add users login.
To this I've got a database with a table "users" and for the moment 3 users.
I've got a php file which can communicate with the database (For exemple it can insert a new user in the table)

To sign up an new user I use this code :

```
const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
let json = 'logUser='+encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(
   {"email":myFormEmail,"password":myFormPassword}
));
this.http.post('http://localhost/logUp.php', json,  {
   headers: headers
});
```

This code call a php file ("logUp.php") which get POST data and insert in the database email & password which are in the form.

My problem is : I want to do a signIn service. So I use the same code as signUp (PHP file get values from the form signIn) but the difference is that I want to return something from the PHP file to the angular app, to say "Yes" this user exist or "No" this user doesn't exist or password is invalid. But I don't know who to do that, I should probably use Promise to wait for a response, but how ?

Thank for help :)

Here is my basic signUp Php file :

```
<?php

        $json = urldecode($_POST['logUser']);
        $json = stripslashes($json);

        $obj = json_decode($json); // Here is my object width email & password
        $db= new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root" ,"", "NAME_OF_DATABASE");

        $db->query("INSERT INTO users(email, password) VALUES('". $obj->email ."', '". hash("sha256", $obj->password). "')");


        mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

Comment: to wait for a reply in the angular app, you have to subscribe to the http call

Comment: I test to .subscribe after the http.post(...) but then ? I've got an object with http response such as "status":"200" or "ok":true, but how can I get back a value  from by php ? I want a boolean for exemple (false if connection fail or true if email&password are valid

Comment: if you return a json object from the php (which you probably should), add `.map(res => res.json()` at the end of `this.http.post(....)`

Comment: Ok so I should have : `this.http.post(url, myJson,{headers}).map(res => res.json().subscribe(data => { ... });` ?
But I've got an error `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`. Sorry, but I don't understand what .map() does

Comment: the map maps the result you get back into what you need. the error is because you dont send a (valid) json response

Comment: What is wrong with my object (in Php) ? --> `$return->isConnected = "true"`, `$myJSON = json_encode($return);`

Comment: thats not json, json is `{"propertyName": "value"}`. in your case, it would be `{"isConnected": true}`

Comment: I still have the same error. In my Php file, at the end I've got `echo $return` with $return the json. This is what I want to get in my angular app, isn't it what the `.map(res => res.json())` get ?

Comment: the .map bit maps the body out into an usable json object which becomes the `res` in the first part of the subscribe

Comment: when you echo `$return`, what does it show you? can you post it?

Comment: In fact it display nothing, because I call the php script but it's not a Php page...but I know that the script is called 'cause if i put `INSERT INTO users(...) VALUES (content ...)` request content will be in the database

Comment: if it displays nothing then it either doesnt run or errors before it can get to the echo

Comment: Yep something was wrong : I wrote `$return = {"isConnected" : false};` and in Php we can't create Json object like this. I comment this line, and then I write `$db->query("INSERT INTO test(emailTest, passwordTest) VALUES('test1', 'test1')");`. After submiting the form, I've got a new value in the "test" table

Comment: try setting `$return` to `$return = ['isConnected' => false];`

Comment: Still have `Unexpected token < in JSON` related to the .map() method (I suppose) _Oh and thank you a lot for help :)_

Comment: the issue is that the json is clearly still invalid, try `.map(res => console.dir(res))` and see what you can see in the body

Comment: I convert the array into a string (`implode($return)`) and now I've got "1" in the _body. What am I suppose to do with that ? How can I get this value ?

Comment: well (res => res.text())` would get the value but you still arent sending json, why did you swap `json_encode` to `implode`?

Comment: It was my mistake, sorry ^^ I return to `echo json_encode($return);` and I now have the good object in the console !!! Well I think that my problem is resolved ?!! Oh You really helped me, it's again a bit confuse for me, but it works so thanks you again :))